# convert a colorbox popup into a normal popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, knockout.js, colorbox

I am currently developing an web application based on asp.net and vb.net.

This application was previously developed by another user and using various types of scripts such as Knockout Javascript, Ajax, Json, JQuery etc.

There are some colorbox popup which is I now want to convert in normal popup. But as I am not very good at ajax and KO-JS I am not being able to convert it.

The following code opens the popup page (send-communication.aspx) as a color-box popup when someone clicks "continue" and that is working fine. But I just want to open it as a normal popup.

The code for link button is

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/_resx/E4.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="new.aspx.vb" Inherits="E4_Jobs_Details_Interview_New" ValidateRequest="false" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
<input type="hidden" name="vid" id="vid" value="<%= Vacancy.ID.ToString()%>" />


     <a href="#" id="saveInt" class="btn">Continue</a>

</asp:Content>
```

And the script for the page is

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptContent">


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

     $(function () {

            var vid = $('#vid').val(), intId = $('#intId').val(), singleBooking = $('#singleInterview').val();


            $('.int-stage').change(function () {   updateCandidates(); });

            $('#saveInt').click(function () {  saveInterview();   });

            var saveInterview = function () {
                var applicants = [];
                $('.int-candidates option:selected').each(function (i, k) {
                   applicants.push($(k).val());
                });

            if (validateInterview(applicants, vm.interviewers(), vm.interviewTimes())) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/_services/UtilityService.asmx/NewInterview',
                    data: "{'id':" + intId + ",'stage': " + $('.int-stage > option:selected').val() + ",'singleBooking':" + singleBooking + ",'reSchedule':'false', 'apps':[" + applicants.join() + "],'location':'" + $('.int-location').val() + "', 'description':'" + $('.int-description').val().replace("'", "&apos;") + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: true,
                    success: function (r) {

                         if((parseInt(r.d))>0) {

                             var commUrl = "/e4/communication/send-communication.aspx?templatetypeid=1&communicationtemplateid=" + $('#intTemplate').val() + "&applicationid=" + applicants.join() + "&interviewid=" + r.d;
                             $.colorbox({ width: '900px', height: '90%', iframe: true, href: commUrl, open: true, overlayClose: false });
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }

        };

    });

    </script>
```

I am new programmer and I am really dumb when it is a case of jquery and KO-JS.

Can any one suggest me how can I open the page (send-sommunication.aspx) as a normal popup instead of a colorbox  popup

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "normal" popup? Do you want to open the page on a new window or tab?

Comment: On a new window as a popup. not on a tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling
`$.colorbox({ width: '900px', height: '90%', iframe: true, href: commUrl, open: true, overlayClose: false });`

Just call
`window.open(commUrl,"","width=900, height=900");`

This will open the url on a new browser window